# Please explain [1,-1][x < 0]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        sign = [1,-1][x < 0]
        rst = sign * int(str(abs(x))[::-1])
        return rst if -(2**31)-1 < rst < 2**31 else 0
```

What does this `[1,-1][x < 0]` mean?

Comment: `[1,-1]` is a list of two elements. `[x < 0]` is indexing that list with a value that can be either False (0) or True (1).

Answer (score 1):

For whatever number greater that 0 the expresion `x < 0` will evaluate to `False` and since `int(False)` evaluates to `0` it returns the value of the first list in index 0.

```
>>> 1 < 0
False
>>> int(1 < 0)
0
>>> [1, -1][int(1 < 0)]
1
```

Completly the opposite for values less than 0.

```
>>> [1,-1][1 < 0]
1
>>> [1,-1][-1 < 0]
-1
```

It is the same as `-1 if x < 0 else 1`